# VB.NET Possible to add outside outline to text (stroke)

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to add an outline, one that continues to expand outwards from the text?

Ie: the outside stroke from Photoshop is what I am looking for

I have found a way to have the outline go inside the text, but it is not what I am looking for.

I've looked around, but I haven't been able to find anyone on google who wanted an outter outline.

Thanks

Current inner outline:

```
    Dim grp As Graphics = e.Graphics
    Dim gp As New Drawing2D.GraphicsPath
    Dim useFont As Font = New Font("Impact", 60, FontStyle.Regular)
    grp.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias
    grp.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
    gp.AddString("3000", useFont.FontFamily, FontStyle.Regular, 60, New Point(0, 0), StringFormat.GenericTypographic)
    useFont.Dispose()

    Dim orangeBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(226, 149, 0))
    grp.FillPath(orangeBrush, gp)

    'This is the stroke below
    Dim blackpen As New Pen(Color.Black, 2)
    grp.DrawPath(blackpen, gp)
    gp.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you reverse the order in which you drawpath and fillpath you can get a outside border for your text.

Comment: Could you include a code example as well please? It does seem self explanatory, but the more information the better